# How to fix a micronaut micrometer bean that is not loaded at application startup

Tags: kotlin, applicationcontext, micronaut, micrometer

A created a simple micronaut application that exposes micrometer metrics. I want to add custom tags, but the bean that does that is not loaded at startup.

What am i missing?
Remark: It does not so on local pc when started with intellj. But it does work when deployed on k8s.

Bean:

```
@Factory
open class MeterFilterFactory {

    @Bean
    @Singleton
    fun addCommonTags(): MeterFilter {
        return MeterFilter.commonTags(
            Arrays.asList(
                Tag.of("service", "my-super-service"),
                Tag.of("special", "tag comes here")
            )
        )
    }
}
```

application config

```
micronaut:
  metrics:
    enabled: true
    sensitive: true
    export:
      prometheus:
        enabled: true
        step: PT1M
        descriptions: true
  distribution:
    percentiles-histogram:
      http.server.requests: true
    sla:
      http.server.requests: 1ms,5ms
  binders:
    logback:
      enabled: false
    processor:
      enabled: false
    uptime:
      enabled: false
```

build gradle

```
    compile "io.micronaut.configuration:micronaut-micrometer-registry-statsd"
    compile "io.micronaut:micronaut-management"
    compile "io.micronaut.configuration:micronaut-micrometer-registry-prometheus"
```

Currently i get back

```
{"name":"system.cpu.usage","measurements":[{"statistic":"VALUE","value":0.07751937984496124}]}
```

but i miss the tags that i tried to add.

Comment: Remark: It does not so on local pc when started with intellj. But it does work when deployed on k8s.

Comment: Solved it. IntelliJ "bug". Annotation processing was enabled but didn't take place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntelliJ cache clearing + restart solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you mark the bean with `@Context` the bean will be initialized when the context is initialized.  See https://docs.micronaut.io/1.0.5/api/io/micronaut/context/annotation/Context.html.

I hope that helps.